# Apply on non-grouped dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to implement a simple func that marks one group as `True`, at random

**Dataframe:**

```
In [145]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,1,1,2,2], 'b': [3,3,3,3,3]})

In [146]: df
Out[146]:
   a  b
0  1  3
1  1  3
2  1  3
3  2  3
4  2  3
```

**Function:**

```
def pickone(df, group, out):
    u = df[group].unique()
    p = np.random.choice(u, 1)[0]
    df[out] = False
    df[df[group]==p][out] = True
    return df
```

**Applying it works fine on grouped dataframes:**

```
In [148]: df.groupby(['b']).apply(pickone, group="a", out="c")
Out[148]:
   a  b      c
0  1  3   True
1  1  3   True
2  1  3   True
3  2  3  False
4  2  3  False
```

**But not on non-grouped dfs**:

```
In [149]: df.apply(pickone, group="a", out="c")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/_libs/index.c:5085)()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item (pandas/_libs/hashtable.c:13892)()

TypeError: an integer is required

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-149-86c0d6e0e423> in <module>()
----> 1 df.apply(pickone, group="a", out="c")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`df` is a DataFrame, while `df.groupby(...)` is a `DataFrameGroupBy` object.
[`DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) and [`DataFrameGroupBy.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) are two completely different methods.

`df.apply` is used to call a function once for each row (by default) or each column.
The function expects a Series (a row or column) as its first argument.

`df.groupby(...).apply` is used to call a function once per group.
The function expects a (sub-)DataFrame as its first argument.

To call `pickone`  on `df`, use

```
pickone(df, group='a', out='c')
```

instead of `df.apply(pickone, ...)`.

---

By the way,

```
df[df[group]==p][out] = True
```

is an assignment using chained indexing. Since, for some DataFrames, `df[df[group]==p]` may return a new DataFrame with data copied from `df`, `df[df[group]==p][out] = True` may modify the new DataFrame rather `df` itself.

Thus, assignments with chained indexing is [considered a no-no](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy). Instead use `df.loc`:

```
df[out] = False
df.loc[df[group]==p, out] = True
```

or, in this case,

```
df[out] = (df[group]==p)
```

suffices.